# Understanding term deterministic and non random

Tags: stochastic, stochastic-process

I am confused about a situation which is presented on the following  slide:

[image]

Last  sentences says that:

It is important to note that deterministic does not mean that
xt is non-random. What  does this mean? If A and B are random variable, then x must be random right?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? I was confused by that as well, surely deterministic means non-random...

Comment: no i am waiting for answer already  for 4 month :D

Comment: OK, I think it's actually a mistake. Usually deterministic means exactly non-random. Here they are redefining the term to mean perfectly predictable random variable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It us a question about operator theory (mathematics).

Answer (score 0):

I think the point may be that nature may choose randomly among different paths, but once you know which path has been chosen you can predict future values of `x_t` on the path from past values `x_{t-1}`, etc.  So e.g. nature may flip a coin to choose between the following two paths:  `x_t=0 for all t`, and `x_t=1 for all t`.  Then if you don't know the path, `x_t` is indeed random.  But once you know `x_{t-1}`, you know `x_t`.